Ordering wordpress posts with multiple meta_values
Im trying to order my posts with some conditionals.
What i need: Filter posts with highlight = 1 then i have another field called 'class_situation' that have many values options that need to be ordered by its value.
Here's what i got so far:
$query->set('meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'highlight_clause' => array(
        'key' => 'highlight',
        'value' => '1',
    ),
    'class_situation_clause' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'class_situation',
            'value' => array('Inscrições Abertas / Confirmado', 'Inscrições Abertas', 'Inscrições Encerradas / Não Confirmado', 'Inscrições Encerradas / Confirmado'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'highlight',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
));

$query->set('orderby', array(
    'highlight_clause' => 'ASC',
    'class_situation_clause' => 'ASC',
),


If i set the orderby for the 'highlight' field its shows the highlighted posts first but the remaning posts are ordered by title. Combinining the two orderby only works for 'highlight'. What im doing wrong?
The only way i can sort by 'class_situation' is removing the filter of 'highlight'.
